# Can Pandas generate a time stamp when a cell is executed?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I'm using an API to pull data from another website, putting it in a DataFrame and creating a visualization.

I want to have the title of the visualization to have the time-stamp from when the API (requests.get) pulls the info so we know exactly what time period the graph is representing.

Question: is there a way for Pandas to create a time stamp and save it in a variable when a specific cell is executed.

something like:
request_time = create current timestamp

This code would be in the same cell as the requests.get...

so I can:
plt.title(f"This graph's info was generated at {request_time}")

This code would be in the cells where I'm creating the visualizations...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
plt.title("This graph's info was generated at " + request_time)
```

EDIT:

It looks like you want to grab the timestamp at the time the request was made, save this to a variable, and add this to your plot title:

```
from datetime import datetime
## Make the API request here
ts = str(pd.to_datetime(datetime.now()))

plt.title("This graph's info was generated at " + ts)
```

Comment: Vishnu - thanks for the quick response. What i'm trying to figure out is how to create a variable that will create the time stamp when a cell is run - specifically when I execute the requests.get